# Why doesn't the text in my div appear?

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development, and want to have a footer with various info at the bottom of my site (and eventually have the banner and info appear upon hovering over where the banner will be). At the moment I have a black banner but the text within will not show. I have tried putting the text between p tags within the div and assigning a bannerText class to no avail. I want the text to allign to the left of the footer. Here is what I have now.

```css
#creditsBanner {
  position: fixed;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: +1;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="creditsBanner">
  Hanadulset
</div>
```

Comment: Your font-size is 100px but the height of the element is only 15px. Change the font-size and you can see the text

Comment: You are using `font-size: 100px` in a div having height only 15px? Such a big `font-size` resulting in text going out of the view of `<div>`. Remove `height` or set `line-height` as well and reduce `font-size` to make the text visible.

Answer (score 0):

because of CSS height value.change to auto

```
#creditsBanner {    
 height:auto    
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1h105ae6/

Answer (score 0):

You apply height 15px and font-size 100px so your text is hidden as there is less height for your text. Removing height will do the job:

```css
#creditsBanner {
  position: fixed;
  /*height: 15px;*/
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size:100px;
  color:white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="creditsBanner">
Hanadulset
</div>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it resolve the problem?

Comment: my bad, added little desc

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the `#creditsBanner`. If you need to reduce the height of the banner use `padding` and `font-size`.

Just like:

```
#creditsBanner {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
}
```

Look at the snippet below:

```css
#creditsBanner {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size:100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="creditsBanner">
  Hanadulset
</div>
```

Hope this helps!